# Why the leaves of my guava getting dry and dropping?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, pruning, leaves, guavas

I have purchased a guava plant one week ago. from the start of having this tree, some of the leaves getting dry and wavy then start to dropping without getting yellow. is this natural or my tree has a disease?

It's near the window and has sunlight about 5 hours a day. The temperature is between 15 and 25 degrees Centigrade, and the humidity is low but I spray water 3 times a week. I am watering my guava about 3 times a week.

[image]
[image]
[image]
and my second question is, is it a good idea to to prune the tree at this time of year (winter)?

Comment: That also looks like way too small of a pot. Time to give your guava a new home!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd repot it into the next size up of pot, and give it a good watering. Looks like the humidity could improve also. I don't see disease on the plant, but that's just from the pics.

About pruning, you can head back some of that long, gangly growth, take out anything dead, broken, or rubbing, etc. I wouldn't prune too hard when it's in that shape though. The ideal time to prune is right before the fastest growth period of the year, as that's when the cuts will heal fastest, and you are least likely to get infected.